# Determining if two rank-3 tensors are related by a rotation/relection

Tags: matrices, tensors, rotations, reflection

I have two rank-3 tensors, let's call them $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$.  Each is a 3x3x3 tensor, representing voxels in an image.  I'd like to determine if $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are related by a rotation / reflection.

For matrices (rank-2 tensors?), I'd assume $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are related by :

$M_{1} = R M_{2}$

Rearrange:

$M_{1} M^{-1}_{2} = R$

Since $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are known and assuming $M_{2}$ is invertible, we can compute $R$. Then we can test if the relation

det$(R) \stackrel{?}{=} \pm 1$

is true. If it is true, then $R$ must be a rotation matrix.

**QUESTION:**

Is there an equivalent relation for rank-3 tensors?

Comment: Just FYI: a rule of thumb for the difference between a matrix and a tensor is that a tensor is tied to the underlying set of points, while matrices are tied to the coordinate system. By establishing a coordinate system, you can use a matrix to represent a rank 2 tensor, but If you change coordinate systems, the matrix changes, while the tensor does not. However, "matrix" is used exclusively for 2D arrays of numbers, while tensors can be of any rank, and are represented by higher dimensional arrays. For this reason "tensor" has been hi-jacked to mean a higher dimensional array, as you do here.

Comment: Something seems funny about your approach here. $T_1$ and $T_2$ represent 3D images. if likewise the elements of $M_1$ and $M_2$ were the pixels of a 2D image, and your purpose was to discover if one image is a rotation/reflection of the other, your method would not work. If I take a $100\times 100$ pixel image, and choose a random $100\times 100$ matrix $R$ with determinant $1$ to multiply it with, the result would look like static, not like the original image rotated.